# Is it possible to send a Steam gift card to someone not yet on Steam?

Tags: steam

I want to give a gift to someone for Christmas. They know they want a game, but not which one and I don't think they are on Steam yet. Don't really want to ask, because of the surprise element. Can I buy a gift card and email them the code to be used once they set up on Steam?

Comment: Cursory research indicates that the digital gift cards do not work that way. However, I think physical gift cards should work.

Comment: What @JohntheGreen said is backed up in http://store.steampowered.com/digitalgiftcards/ digital cards seem to require to be linked to an account, whereas physical ones do not

Answer (score 1):

You can get a physical Steam gift card available in some stores and mail it to them. there would be a code inside ready for when they get steam.